# Can I iterate through a for loop randomly instead of sequentially?

Tags: c#, java, loops, for-loop, control-structure

If there is a for loop like

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
{
   //block of code
}
```

What I want to achieve is, after first iteration i value need not to be 1, it can be anything from 1 to 10, i should not be 0 again and similarly for other iterations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple algorithm:

- create an array containing numbers from 0 to 10
- shuffle
- iterate over that array and retrieve the corresponding index in the initial collection

In Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> random = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    Collections.shuffle(random);

    List<String> someList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k");

    for (int i : random) {
        System.out.print(someList.get(i));
    }
}
```

outputs:

> ihfejkcadbg

**EDIT**

Now that I reread it, you could also simply shuffle the initial collection and loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> someList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j");

    //make a copy if you want the initial collection intact
    List<String> random = new ArrayList<> (someList);
    Collections.shuffle(random);

    for (String s : random) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that: first, create a [*random permutation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) of numbers `0`..`N-1`, and then iterate like this:

```
int[] randomPerm = ... // One simple way is to use Fisher-Yates shuffle
for (int i in randomPerm) {
    ...
}
```

[Link to Fisher-Yates shuffle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle)

Answer (score 2):

The "shuffle" approach is probably the easiest, but pulling them out in random order can work too; the main problem with this is that `RemoveAt` is relatively expensive. Shuffling would be cheaper. Included for completeness:

```
var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
var rand = new Random();
while (list.Count > 0) {
    int idx = rand.Next(list.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(list[idx]);
    list.RemoveAt(idx);
}
```

Comment: this one answers the question if it is 0 through 10 ,what if Enumerable range start seed is from a non-zero number for instance like this Enumerabl.Range(5,10)

Comment: @101010 you'd add the offset in about 2 lines of code; not a biggie